# Tooltip stays visible on click of imagebutton

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have an ImageButton with a tooltip. On clicking the button, the tooltip stays visible and sticks to the mouse on the page. I want the tooltip to disappear once the button has been clicked but can't find a way to do this.

Any advice would be appreciated!
markup:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mark as Read">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="img_markAsRead" runat="server" ImageUrl="img/icons/eye.png" CssClass="tooltip" Width="20"  ToolTip="Mark this Notification as Read" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("notification_id")%>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**CSS :**

```
.ui-tooltip {
    padding: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    max-width: 300px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #aaa;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #aaa;
}
```

**Code behind :**

```
protected void grdv_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow theRow = grdv_notifications.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
    ImageButton theButton = (ImageButton)theRow.FindControl("img_markAsRead");
    string notificationNo = theButton.CommandArgument;

    #region the clever sql statement to do the updates

    #endregion

    //reload the gridview
    loadGridview();

    //set the notification number       
    MasterPage master = (MasterPage)this.Master;
    master.updateNotificationCount(grdv_notifications.Rows.Count);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After racking my brain, the answer was simple.

Adding a     `Response.Redirect("notifications.aspx");`

to reload the page after clicking on the ImageButton reloaded the page and cleared out the tooltip. 
Simple, but effective!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your *jQuery* tag and the fact that the class name is "ui-tooltip", I'm guessing that you're using jQuery UI tooltip.  In which case, one of the options is "track", which you can set to *false* when you initialise...

```
$( document ).tooltip({
  track: false
});
```

This should be *false* by default though, so you must be setting it to *true*.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work. The tooltip is still visible after clicking on the image after adding this code.

Comment: Have you got an demo we can look at?

Comment: The best thing to do is create an isolated test case which replicates the problem, in something like CodePen or JSBin, so that you can post the link and we can see it.  Alternatively, if it's on a live site that we can access, then give us the link to that.